# Google API client library in javascript not working locally

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus

I tried to run the sample given [here](https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html) on my web server which is Google App Engine server.

I modified the clientId and apiKey with clientId and clientSecret from my google cloud console.

When I run, I see in javascript console a **400 Bad Request** for

> https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/plus/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0&key=TO6faADFEmHdfdh08mm8XgR

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the sample is working on the server you linked. As Ian mentioned, the sample you are running looks a little outdated, the [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript) is the latest and greatest and uses the Google+ Sign-In button which has a number of enhancements, particularly when you are using client-side authorization.

To test that your sample is working, you can open the Chrome developer tools and run some simple client library code such as:

```
gapi.client.plus.activities.list(
  {userId: 'me'}).execute(
    function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    });
```

If you see your activity feed, everything is working.

Regarding locally ... In order for the JavaScript library to work, you also must be running a web server on your computer such as the Python Simple HTTP Server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

or Apache, twistd, etc.

If you directly open the file, permissions will prevent the library from working.

Your authorized JavaScript origins must also match the port (and protocol, e.g. https/http) that are set up in your [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) project. If it's working remotely but not locally, you might be missing a localhost origin.

Comment: By "locally" i mean on a local server. I was using GAE. And it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty old sample! Try https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript for a newer one.

With regards to this problem: don't put your client secret in the key field! The client secret should never be put into public, it should only ever be used on a server where it can be kept private. The API key in this case is a separate entry (the simple API access browser key).

More about API keys: https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys